# Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

When I trying to build my app, I got the following errors:

```
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\browser.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(22,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(23,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(46,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(52,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(66,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(72,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(88,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-collections\es6-collections.d.ts(103,5): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-promise\es6-promise.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>node_modules\angular2\typings\es6-promise\es6-promise.d.ts(42,16): error TS2300: Build: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
```

I don't understand why. Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/appScripts/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have no clue why I get this error. I have followed this tutorial: http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0):

Check your es6-collections.d.ts is imported more than once. This type of issue occurs when the reference is made more than once.